# Custom tag file code assist not working in Eclipse but working in IntelliJIDEA

Tags: java-ee-6

I am new to JavaEE but struggling hard to learn it.

I noticed one thing which is not working that is Code Assist in Custom Tag files in Eclipse. Same working in IntelliJIDEA current version. Both screen shots below.

Someone help me to enable Code Assist in Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2.

***Edited***

NetBeans & Esclipse don't show code assist for custom classes when I type ${user.} which is EL. Only IntelliJIDEA supports that.

**Eclipse**

[image: Eclipse]

**IntelliJIDEA**

[image: IntelliJIDEA]

**JAR files**

[image: Jar Files]

Comment: Does content assist work elsewhere in the file? For example, you should be able to click just after com.example in the tag import line, then do ctrl-space, and it should show you the available classes in that package. Also, if you just click enter in the body and press ctrl-space, it should give you some options.

Comment: @jeremy-goodell Yes code assist working fine for what you have mentioned above. I even added jstl1.2.jar with <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> and I see code assist but in ${} if I type user than I don't see my properties for that type. Expression Language code assist not working right?

Comment: ${pageContext. } code completion working but for my custom classes not working if I type ${user.} no code assist popup.

Comment: Then I would have to say that eclipse DOES support content assist for taglibs, but not for tag files. I believe it is a fairly simple matter to create a tld file that would solve the problem as I mentioned in the comments below. Sorry to lead you on a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try Window / Preferences / Web / JSP Files / Editor / Content Assist.

Make sure the HTML and XML Tag Proposals checkboxes are checked.

2) Can you specify it as a taglib instead of a tag import?

```
<%@ tablib prefix="user" uri="/WEB-INF/tags/User.tld" %>
```

3) Do you have the right libraries in the classpath?
[Enabling content assist for JSP files](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.sse.doc.user/topics/tsrcedt023.html)

Having the proper files defined in the Java™ build class path is essential for content assist to work properly in JSP files. It is also essential for the links builder to be able to correctly resolve links to servlets or Java beans in JSP and HTML files.
To enable content assist for JSP files:

To determine whether the build path is correct, select Properties from the
project's pop-up menu. Select Java Build Path, and then the Libraries page. You should see the following files:

```
    j2ee.jar
    rt.jar
    servlet.jar
    webcontainer.jar
```

If they are not present, add them as External JAR files. You may have your own versions of these files, depending on the level of JDK or Servlet API for which you are developing. If your Web applications reference other JARs, you can place them in the build path as follows:

```
Use the Add JARs button on the Library page.
You must ensure that the JAR file is available to the server by properly
    configuring the server.
Add the JARs to the WEB-INF/lib directory.
    They will be automatically added to the build path and deployed to the
    server in as part of the project WAR.
```

Comment: I added something else to try.

Comment: See my question added my JAR file list as image. I am working on what you said.

Comment: In solution 2 what would be in User.tld?

Comment: Tried 3 but no success. Still no code assistance even added jar files. I will try to work on 2. Can you confirm TLD code assist work for you?

Comment: tld code assist works for me, but not tag import as you've specified it. You can try it out using a pre-defined tag library. Add 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> at the top of your jsp and then type <c: and see if you get code assist (you may need the jstl.jar library on your class path to use that taglib though).

Comment: Also, please see question I asked in the comment on the original question above.

Comment: Replied above in comment of my question.